# Cart Shipping estimate not rendering html correctly

Tags: cart, shipping, onestepcheckout

I've installed aditional shipping method module on my site, and getting the strage error.

Please see image.

For some reason in the Cart it doesn't render the content correctly, but when I go to pay and there also can pick a shipping method it's rendered ok?

Checked out the code of both pages and the code is the same on both:
[image]

Comment: How are you generating the block associated with the `available.phtml` ? Ensure you're escaping everything output wise as well.

Comment: Hey, the bad code is in `/cart/shipping.phtml` I did check the both codes and they are basically the same (compared with Available.phtml). Where should I add the Escape you're refering to? So it would be rendered correctly? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you inspect the element on the cart page. As 2 different phtml files are in use here it looks like you are missing a tag close or something. You should see a console error showing you what is wrong.

If still can't detect then suggest take a step back and put in default shipping.phtml and then once ensure this is rendering then build it up slowly.